# QMAKE *.pro-file: enable debugging info in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, settings, qmake

because of compatibility issues, I compile my project in VS2008 in release mode, but I need to access debug information. That is why I manually set up debugging settings in project properties for release mode. In VS2008, I open Properties window and select:

1. Configuration Properties/C/C++/Optimization = Disable /Od
2. Configuration Properties/C/C++/General/Debug Information Format = Program Database (/Zi)
3. Configuration Properties/C/C++/Linker/Generate Debug Info = Yes (/DEBUG)

I use a pro-file to configure my project's vcproj-file. Every time I alter this pro-file, I have to reload my project and the the debug settings are lost. I want to include three settings mentioned above into the pro-file, so that after changing it, I do not need to set up debugging settings again.

I have already googled and I have also looked my question up in [QT reference](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html), but I could not find anything. I will be happy to receive any suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK guys, I have figured it out.

In the QMAKE file `myproject.pro`, insert following commands:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /Zi 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /Od
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /DEBUG
```

This should work!