# How to disable adding 'd' suffix to debug library name in qmake on windows?

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake

I created project for QML C++ plugin in QtCreator and debug version have 'd' suffix appended to the name, for example `plugind.dll` instead of `plugin.dll`. How can configure project not to add this suffix? Qt version 4.8.1, windows 7.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Are you aware that you CANT load debug plugin into release version, so its somehow pointless

Comment: @KamilKlimek: I want to debug my plugin. Yes, I found, that I can't use debug version of plugin in release version. But I found different solution: [enable debug information in the release build](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9258074/810123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this line into the .pro file:

**TARGET = YourProgramName**