# How to deal with varying library names in .pro files on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt

If you build libraries with Qt, depending on if that is a Debug or Release build the library will have "d" suffix in its name. For example:

```
QtCored.dll
```

Then, if you want to link it to your application you have to link the correct version (debug or release) which means explicitly naming them each time in .pro file.

```
Release:LIBS += -llib1 -llib2 -llib3
Debug:LIBS += -llib1d -llib2d -llib3d
```

This is a possible(and usual) scenario for a .pro file as far as I can tell.

The problem is - isn't it a little too extreme on the programmer? If the environment *already knows* that it is building in release mode for example, why are we forced to retype everything 2 times? Is there really no mechanism to tell Qt "append d suffix to all libraries in that entry" ?

So far, I am doing this:

```
//(in a globally included .pro file)
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
    windows:DADD=d
} else {
    DADD=
}
//in actual .pro file
LIBS += -llib1$${DADD} -llib2$${DADD} -llib3$${DADD}
```

but it feels extremely bad style to do that... Is there a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, do it from code.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#pragma comment (lib, "QtCore.dll")
#else
#pragma comment (lib, "QtCored.dll")
#endif
```

Or if you need more

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define DEBUGSUFFIX ""
#else
#define DEBUGSUFFIX "d"
#endif
#pragma comment (lib, "QtCore" DEBUGSUFFIX ".dll")
#pragma comment (lib, "Etc" DEBUGSUFFIX ".dll")
```

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to put that?

Comment: also, this is, arguably, even worse. delving into code to solve the work that should be done in a pro file is really bad in my opinion

Comment: also, is this supported on mingw?

Comment: In at least one .cpp file. (That's what I meant with "do it from code" ). Qt is fairly friendly; I've used this method to calculate the correct library name when it contained a version number. And MinGW isn't smart enough for this (Boost calls it autolinking)

Comment: But what if I have a library subproject that has another library included - will I have to include this into yet another cpp file, now inside this library?

Comment: Check out how it works. You don't need additional files anywhere.

Comment: This kinda moves the library inclusion to an unspecified cpp file which feels really awkward. I don't argue that it solves the problem, but to me it looks like it is as bad if not worse as the solution I use atm

Comment: Well, the compiler doesn't care how it got into a .cpp file, so if you feel it should go into `stdafx.h` then that's also fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I feel. The job of specifying correct library names to include in qt is the job of qmake working on a .pro file. Everyone else working with this project will not know what it _feels_ like to me. They will go look into .pro file and will immediately be confused by not finding it there

Comment: I'm mostly surprised that [it's actually needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295514/how-to-disable-adding-d-suffix-to-debug-library-name-in-qmake-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: It is needed. There are valid reasons to having debug and release versions of libraries side by side in a folder. The answer in the post you linked removes that flexibility

Comment: This is bad advice. The asker is using `qmake`, and the build system will handle library paths as necessary. Hiding library dependencies from the build system and adding them directly using windows-only pragmas is asking for trouble, and adding platform-specific code for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The environment can't know that you have release and debug versions of your library available. These libraries could be coming from anywhere.

Your solution is one of the two typical approaches. The other way is to have `Debug` and `Release` folders for the libraries, and only change the library path, without changing library names.

I don't see how the extra few dozen characters in the .pro file can be considered burdensome. The reality is that if you have projects of substantial size and complexity, you'll have huge project files, whether they are qmake, qbs or cmake. This will be the least of your problems, so I'd say don't sweat it too much.

Given that you're using `qmake` your question isn't really Windows-related at all. An answer will work on all platforms.

Comment: so I am not the only one to invent conditional suffix token ?:)

Comment: @Zeks There's really no other way to do it if you insist on the `d` suffix. The typical way of dealing with such things would be a separate out-of-source build for debug and release, and then your question becomes a NO-OP. That's what Qt Creator does by default. So it seems to me you're making up a problem in search of a solution :)